# How to increase the size of icons in jqgrid?

Tags: html, jqgrid

How should I increase the size of icons(add,delete..) in jqgrid?I have written following code in ui.jqgrid.css

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div  span.ui-icon,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div  span.ui-icon{float:left;margin: 2px; width:18px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager {border-left: 0 none !important;border-right: 0 none !important; border-top: 0 none 
!important; margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; position: relative;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: Please include always **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and **the fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). The styles included in `ui.jqgrid.css` depend on CSS framework, which you use (jQuery UI or Bootstrap). Recent versions of jqGrid support to use not only old raster jQuery UI icons, but Font Awesome or Bootstrap icons. Increased raster icons looks bad, but vector icons like Font Awesome could be good increased.

Comment: Finally it's important to write **which icons** you want to increase: navigator icons (add/edit), `formatter: "actions"` , pager icons (first, previous, next, last page), sorting icons etc. For example, jqGrid use closing icon in every dialog. Do you want to increase the icon too or your question only about navigator icons for example.

Comment: I want to increase the font of all icons like edit,add,delete,refresh and so on.And I am using jqGrid  5.2.1 this version of jqgrid

Comment: Sorry, but I provide no support for **commercial** [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use. I develop *alternative* fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which could be used completely free of completely free of charge under MIT or GPLv2 licenses (the same like in old jqGrid in versions <=4.7). The icons, which you mention are only the icons from the **navigator** bar. One can easy increase there in free jqGrid. If you have interest I could post the answer. In any way I'd recommend you to use vector icons instead of bad resizable PNG icons.

Comment: Can we use FontAwesome icons for increasing the size?

Comment: Yes of cause. The icons are vector based and can be resized to any size without reducing of quality. See [here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/trash-o/) for example. To use Font Awesome in free jqGrid one need just add `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option. I suggested you to answer on your question in case of usage **free jqGrid** fork *instead* of **commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS**, but you don't answer, whether you need it.

Comment: Actually I am very new to the jqgrid so I don't have any idea about it.But I want to use this version only so how can proceed with it for increasing the size?Please can you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free jqGrid supports vector based Font Awesome icons as alternative to raster icons of jQuery UI. To use Font Awesome you need just include the CSS of Font Awesome and to add `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option. For example, https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9f9exg91/1/ uses the following simple code

```js
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
    colModel: [...],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    ...
});
```

which displays

[image]

If you want for example increase the size of navigator icons in 1.5 of the standard size you can just add CSS rule

```css
.navtable .ui-pg-button {
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

and get the navigator buttons

[image]

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9f9exg91/2/. You can see that the navigator buttons are wrapped automatically. See the wiki article.

If you want in increase the size of all the buttons of the pager then you can use CSS rule

```css
.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button {
    font-size: 150%;
}
```

alternatives. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9f9exg91/3/, which displays

[image]

Free jqGrid supports additionally `iconsOverText: true` option, which allows to get the following look of icons:

[image]

see https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9f9exg91/4/

In general you can customize the buttons in easy way like you need. For example you can go to some button generator page like [this one](http://css3buttongenerator.com/) create custom button and to copy the CSS styles to `.ui-jqgrid .navtable .ui-pg-button`. I did this and created the next demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9f9exg91/6/, which displays the following navigator bars:

[image]

Below you can find the CSS rules used in the last demo:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .navtable .ui-pg-button:not(.ui-state-hover) {
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8;
    -moz-border-radius: 8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #666666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #666666;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #666666;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    border: solid #0089de 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-jqgrid .navtable .ui-pg-button.ui-state-hover,
.ui-jqgrid .navtable .ui-pg-button:hover{
    background: #3cb0fd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I used additional `pagerRightWidth: 100` option in the last demo to fix the right part of the pager and to provide more place for the navigator icons.

**UPDATED:** One can use top pager by usage of `toppager: true` instead of `pager: true` or to use both pagers. If one would replace `.navtable` in the above CSS rules to `.ui-pg-table` then the style will be applied to all buttons of the pager: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/9f9exg91/9/

[image]

Comment: I have done that but when I am selecting a row then other row is highlighted even the icons are not getting displayed according the sequence I have written.   
  $("#list1").jqGrid("navGrid","#prowed1",
    {
     cloneToTop:true,
     formatter : "checkboxFontAwesome4",
         addicon:"fa fa-plus ",
     add : true,
     delicon:"fa fa-trash",
     del : true,
     searchicon:"fa fa-search",
     search : true,
     refreshicon:"fa fa-refresh",
     refresh : true,
     editicon:"fa fa-edit ",
     edit : true,
     saveicon : 'fa fa-floppy-o',
     save : true,
      },

Comment: @Aishwarya: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you describe the problem more clear? How one can reproduce the problem? Is it exist on some demoes, which I posted or you can modify one from the demo so that it has the problem? Could you describe step by step what should be done to reproduce the problem inclusive expected results and what you have instead. By the way the call of `navGrid`, which you included contains a lot of unneeded parameters or just wrong options (like `formatter`). I think that call can be reduced to `$("#list1").jqGrid("navGrid");`

Comment: I have asked one question for that

Comment: @Aishwarya: What you asked? Where? What problem you have?

Comment: Will it run for inline nav?what changes I have to do?Like for inline navigation what I need to do?

Comment: @Aishwarya: CSS settings, which I described in my answer, works with any icons of the navigator bar or pager. See https://jsfiddle.net/9f9exg91/11/

Comment: What my question is I want to make edit icon inline editable so how can do that?Can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014297/selected-row-not-highlighted-in-jqgrid this link also?

Comment: @Aishwarya: You should describe more clear what you want. The statement "I want to make edit icon inline editable" is absolutely unclear. You asked about inline nav in your previous comment and I added the call of `inlineNav` in https://jsfiddle.net/9f9exg91/11/. Is it what you need? I suppose that you use wrong terminology. If you don't know exact terminology then you should at least describe more detailed what you need. It could be that you want to use `formatter: "actions"` to add buttons in every row of the grid (like on the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/).

Comment: Whenever I will click on edit icon then it should edit the columns in that row only like inline editing But what it is doing it is redirecting to one form/box there we need to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing some valid information but you can always use zoom in your CSS over proper selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to increase the font-size - see the classes

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view
```

and increase the font size you want.

Since you use Guriddo jqGrid 5.2.1 you can get quick and professional response in [our public forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4)

Comment: I have tried this .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-view {position: relative;left:0; top: 0; padding: 0; font-size:20px; z-index:100;} but still it is not increasing the font size