# Selected row not highlighted in jqgrid

Tags: html, jqgrid

I have written the function for row selection.It is not highlighting the selected row(sometimes highlighting sometimes other row highlighted) and not displaying the icons the way I have written it. following is the code  
                    `multiselect : true,
                   iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                    datatype : "json",
                    loadonce : true,
                    rowNum : 10,
                    rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                    toppager:true,
                    pager : '#prowed1',
                    sortname : 'id',
                    viewrecords : true,
                    sortorder : "asc",
                    editurl : "editGrid.html",
                    onSelectRow : function(rowId) {
                        var rowId = jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('getGridParam',
                                'selarrrow');
                        if (rowId.length > 1) {
                            $("#list1_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        }
                    },`

```
$("#list1").jqGrid(
            "navGrid",
            "#prowed1",
            {
                cloneToTop:true,
                formatter : "checkboxFontAwesome4",
                 addicon:"fa fa-plus ",
                add : true,
                delicon:"fa fa-trash",
                del : true,
                searchicon:"fa fa-search",
                search : true,
                refreshicon:"fa fa-refresh",
                refresh : true,
                editicon:"fa fa-edit ",
                edit : true,
                saveicon : 'fa fa-floppy-o',
                save : true,

            },`{ // edit options
                afterSubmit : function() {
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                beforeShowForm : function(form) {
                    $("td .navButton navButton-ltr").hide();
                },
                closeAfterEdit : true
            },
            { // add options
                beforeShowForm : function(form) {
                    $("#buName").removeAttr("readonly");
                },
                closeAfterAdd : true,
                clearAfterAdd : true
            },
            { // del options
                serializeDelData : function(postdata) {
                    return {
                        'buName' : $('#list1').jqGrid('getCell',
                                postdata.id, 'buName'),
                        'oper' : 'del'
                    }
                }
            }

    );` $("#list1").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#prowed1", {
        //cloneToTop:true,
        //iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        add : false,
        edit : true,
        editicon : 'fa fa-pencil-square-o',
        save : true,
        saveicon : 'fa fa-floppy-o',
        editParams : {
            aftersavefunc : function(id) {
                jQuery('#list1').jqGrid('setSelection', id, false);
            },
        },
    });`
```

Comment: You should provide **the demo**, which reproduce the problem. The reason of the most problems with highlighted: wrong input data or wrong `colModel`. Every row of jqGrid have always `id` attribute (rowid), which should be part of input data: see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div). The id value must be **unique**. If you have id duplicates then you could problems with selection/highlighting of rows.

Comment: Yes it has the problem of id.It contains duplicate id.So how should I remove that? Because I am taking the data from database so I cannot change id.I mean which code should I add?

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the demo, which reproduce the problem. The reason of the most problems with highlighted: wrong input data or wrong `colModel`. Every row of jqGrid have always id attribute (rowid), which should be part of input data: see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div). The id value must be unique. If you have id duplicates then you could problems with selection/highlighting of rows.

If you fill the data from the database than you can use native ids from the tables of the database to build unique rowids. Database tables don't allow id duplicates too.

To be able to edit the data in the database you will need to *identify* the edited data. Such unique value could be used as the rowid. If you fill the grid by JOIN from multiple tables, than **composed id** could be used. For example, if you fill the the grid with the data from two tables User and Location then the paar (user_id, location_id) are unique. If both user_id and location_id are numbers, then you can use `user_id + "_" + location_id` as rowid. The value will be sent to the server during editing and you will have full information to find the data in the tables, which need be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have problems with unique id in the data. Check that the ids used when you insert data in the grid are unique and you do not have duplicate one.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your `ColModel` make sure the property `key:true` is only specified once and represents a unique row ID value. See http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options

Answer (score 0):

Dumb on my part, but I had the property beforeSelectRow set in the grid code that I had copied from another project. This of course was blocking any selection of a grid row.

```
    beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
        return false;
    },
```